# Converting Decimal to Binary to ASCII to Text String w/ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I got to a point in my program where I have a decimal that used to be a string that said “Hello World”. I want to turn this decimal back into the string “Hello World”. I think I need to turn the decimal back into binary, then into its ascii, then into a string. (To get from the string to the decimal in the beginning, I used online converters, but that was because in the beginning I was working with constant numbers, but now I want to use some sort of built in python methods.) How can I do this?

Comment: First, I had
“m = “Hello World””
Next, I used https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-binary.html to make it into 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100. Then I used https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter to get
“m_bi_dec = 87521618088882533792115812”
I want to turn this back into “Hello World”, but without using online converters and such. Instead, I’d like to use some python functions and such.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String -> Binary -> Decimal

```
s = 'Hello World'
b = ''.join(bin(ord(c))[2:].rjust(8, '0') for c in s)
d = int(b, 2)
```

Decimal -> Binary -> String

```
d = 87521618088882533792115812
tmp_b = bin(d)[2:]
b = tmp_b.rjust(len(tmp_b) + 8 - len(tmp_b) % 8, '0')
s = ''.join(chr(int(b[i: i + 8], 2)) for i in range(0, len(b), 8))
```

Comment: Could you explain how  ''.join(bin(ord(c))[2:].rjust(8, '0') for c in s) works and what it does? Could you also explain how and what tmp_b = bin(d)[2:] and tmp_b.rjust(len(tmp_b) + 8 - len(tmp_b) % 8, '0') do? Thanks in advance